# combine text input types jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

in this link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/textinputs/ at the bottom there are several different text input types.

Now my question is how could I combine the **tel** and **password** types? The *tel* types enables the user to display the number pad (key pad) on the mobile device if that type receives focus instead of showing the regular keyboard. The *password* type hides the characters that the user types. Since the password on my webpage will only consists of digits it would be nice if I could combine the functionality of the *tel* type and *password* type.

Comment: This seems hacky but what about making it a `type="number"` input and then changing it to `type="password"` after the user focuses the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pattern="[0-9]*"` attribute to achieve this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" pattern="[0-9]*" id="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your numeric password">
```

It totally works on iOS.