# How to Combine Input of Number and Password in Ionic (Cordova-based)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Based on this docs :

http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/

There are many types of HTML5 input. The 2 of them are Number and Password. How to combine them?

I am not sure whether the tag-attribute value is similar with Cordova or not, because Ionic Framework is based on Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

Use AngularJS **ng-pattern** directive.

```
Use following code pen:
```

http://codepen.io/astockwell/pen/JyCva

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this question is answered before: [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328983/combine-text-input-types-jquery-mobile)

I do not know however if this works correctly with ionic, but I wouldn't know why it shouldn't :)

Answer (score 0):

JS can handle number on the fly

```
<input type="password" name="password" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,''),alert('only numbers')" id="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your numeric password">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr9hk1oh/)